# Google Play application domain

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

After publishing an application into Google Play (and then download it from there) from what remote host (my app) server will receive requests? Is it something like com.my.app in reverse?

I need it for a white list.

Answer (score 0):

You can download it from this link.
It look like this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.app

Answer (score 0):

The package name of an application is used just for unique identifier.
There is no relation to actual connection on the Internet.

Remote addresses will be the app's users' own.